# How to change the frame of the tableCell's imageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, layout

I want to display an imageview in UITableViewCell at right side of each cell by objective c code. I had used following code but it displays the image at left side. Frame is not setting.

```
UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width/2, 0, cell.frame.size.width/2, cell.frame.size.height)];

       if([[self.categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isKindOfClass:[SpecialPagesCategory class]]) {
           cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
           bgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fbBtn.png"];
       } else {
           cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
           bgView.image = nil;
       }

       cell.imageView.image = bgView.image;
       cell.imageView.frame = bgView.frame;
```

How to reset the UITableViewCell imageView by our custom frame? And i am creating a cell like follows

```
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        [self.categoryTable flashScrollIndicators];
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:OPEN_SANS size:16.0];
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; }
```

I had tried by Content View also as follows

```
UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width/2, 0, cell.frame.size.width/2, cell.frame.size.height)];
if([[self.categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isKindOfClass:[SpecialPagesCategory class]]) {
           cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
           bgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fbBtn.png"];
           [cell.contentView addSubview: bgView];
       } else {
           cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
           bgView.image = nil;
           [cell.contentView addSubview: bgView];
       }
```

Problem with "Content View" is imageview is not removed for the cell which doesn't satisfy the if condition

Comment: Why don't you use custom cell ?

Comment: Already coded without custom cell, so team leader told to do without custom cell

Comment: why you are using `cell.imageView`. create own imageview like you've create `bgView` and set your frame.

Comment: Already tried by adding an imageview by cell.contentView as subview, but images are not removed for cells which not satisfy the condition

Answer (score 1):

Create image view and add as a subview to cell, It will work.

```
UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 50, 50)];// Your specification


 imgView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 [imgView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
 [imgView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
 [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData: imageData]];
 [  cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
```

Comment: This code isn't good for a well written project. Firstly, it isn't valid with MVC, which is a basic pattern in iOS. Secondly, it will never refresh the frame. Thirdly, you don't have any coding style.

Comment: I had created a custom table view cell and fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Override this method:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
   [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

   [self.myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
}
```

Where ofc you should replace myImageView with your image view and set proper size of frame.

BTW, code quality tip: I'd also advise to read about MVC and keep this code in `UITableViewCell` subclass implementation file under `layoutSubviews` method.